# How to ensure single initialization of shared stack-allocated pthread_mutex_t? (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

What is an advisable/standard way to ensure that stack-allocated pthread_mutex_t objects are initialized only once in a multithreaded environment?

The `pthread_mutex_init()` man page says:

> Attempting to initialise an already initialised mutex results in
>   undefined behaviour.

I have a `.cpp` file which is compiled to a shared library. A simplification of this file would be:

```
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_mutex_t g_mutex;

int initialize()
{
  pthread_mutex_init( &g_mutex, NULL );
  pthread_mutex_lock( &g_mutex );
  // Do init stuff.
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &g_mutex );
  return 0;
}
```

`initialize()` may be called in a multithreaded environment. So as-is, `pthread_mutex_init()` may be called multiple times on the same object, which is undefined behavior, as quoted above. So that would require thread-safety...by using another mutex. But then who initializes that mutex in a threadsafe manner, ad infinitum...?

Is it legal to call `pthread_mutex_init()` at the global scope (i.e. the same scope as the `pthread_mutex_t` object declaration) as below, and is this considered a "correct" solution to this situation?

```
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_mutex_t g_mutex;
static int g_res = pthread_mutex_init( &g_mutex, NULL );

int initialize()
{
  // g_mutex already initialized (?) so no need to do so here.
  pthread_mutex_lock( &g_mutex );
  // Do init stuff.
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &g_mutex );
  return 0;
}
```

**What I have tried**:

I compiled and ran the second code-block, both of which succeed.

But I still wanted to ask the community because I'm a bit unclear about the legality of calling the `pthread_mutex_init()` function at the global scope, and I wanted to make sure the executable didn't just appear to work because of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it legal to call `pthread_mutex_init()` at the global scope (i.e. the same scope as the `pthread_mutex_t` object declaration) as below, and is this considered a "correct" solution to this situation?

It would not be legal in C, but it's ok in C++.  Since you're initializing the mutex with default attributes, however, it would be preferable to use the initializer macro:

```
static pthread_mutex_t g_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: I'd read about `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` as well, but then that prompts the question _what if default attributes won't do?_. I'm also curious, what happens with the "solution" code in a C compiler? Is that a compile or runtime error?

Comment: @StoneThrow, The proposed solution will be rejected by a conforming C compiler.

Comment: "but it's ok in C++"...so I guess in C++ if default attributes won't do, it'd be acceptable to declare a `pthread_mutexattr_t` statically and pass that as the argument to the global function call to `pthread_mutex_init()`...? I am curious how this situation is solved in C. Maybe I'll ask as a separate question.

Comment: @StoneThrow, generally speaking, one wants to set up each synchronization object before starting the second thread / process that will access it, as indeed is achieved by providing an initializer expression.  If you can't do that for whatever reason, then you're pretty much obligated to rely on a second synchronization object, as you describe in the question.  In that case, one hopes that that second synchronization object can be statically initialized, and I've never come across a situation in which that was not possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
static int g_res = pthread_mutex_init( &g_mutex, NULL );
```

is fine in C++ code, but doesn't work in C code (yes, your code is pure C++, but someone will try it in C...)

For C (or an alternative in C++) per [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html):

> ...
>
> In cases where default mutex attributes are appropriate, the macro
>   PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER can be used to initialize mutexes. The
>   effect shall be equivalent to dynamic initialization by a call to
>   pthread_mutex_init() with parameter attr specified as NULL. ...

Like this:

```
static pthread_mutex_t g_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: Same question as to @JohnBollinger: 
 
I'd read about PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER as well, but then that prompts the question what if default attributes won't do?. I'm also curious, what happens with the "solution" code in a C compiler? Is that a compile or runtime error?

Comment: @StoneThrow What I'd do in that case is either put my mutex initialization code where I *knew* it could only be called once (a shared object initialization function, for example, that's run only once when the shared object is loaded, or I'd use a static mutex initialized with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` to protect my more complex initialization code.  FWIW, Linux provides extensions that can be used to initialize other, non-default mutexes such as `PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP`.  See http://elias.rhi.hi.is/libc/Mutexes.html